# Creating a View or custom content query web part to show all files checked out by logged in user

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I know that there are some answers out there to show an *admin* all of the checked out files by a user... i.e. these two links:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12966.sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-list-the-documents-checked-out-with-version-details-in-a-site-collection.aspx

http://myspworld.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/retrieve-a-list-of-all-items-checked-out-in-a-site-using-powershell/

However, what if I want the ability to be given to all users.  So that a standard user can come onto the site, click a button or link, and be directed to a page that lists all files that they have checked out.  Is there an easy way to implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In 2010, use the OOTB web part "Relevant Documents." Look for it within the web part Category "Content Rollup."

When you edit a Relevant Documents web part properties, you will find the following options under "Data":

1. Include documents last modified by me
2. Include documents created by me
3. Include documents checked out to me

If you choose the third option, the web part will display all documents checked out to the currently logged in user from within that sub web.

Note the limitation on documents that reside within the current web, not the entire site collection.

Comment: this works great, but I can't "select all" to check in everything.  It just shows me a list.  Any ideas to take it the extra step?

Comment: That's another matter, @Shackrock. To my knowledge, there is no way to enable bulk checkins by end users from within that web part (OOTB).

Answer (score 0):

Create the view filtered on "Checked out to" = [Me] should work

Comment: This will only apply to the current view though, I want it to search an entire site.

Comment: In that case you might try something like this:
http://www.the-north.com/sharepoint/post/Further-Customise-CQWP-to-Display-Draft-and-Checked-Out-Pages-By-User
but then you change the CAML query to only include the current user:
http://davehunter.co.uk/2009/07/23/caml-query-that-filters-on-the-current-user/